# CKeditor how to use with Bower

Tags: javascript, java, ckeditor, bower, rich-text-editor

I'm trying to make some html rich text editor. I've already installed CKeditor from Bower like in documentation of CKeditor:

```
{
  "name": "my-project",
  "dependencies": {
    "ckeditor": "4"
  }
}
```

But I don't know how to use it, in the documentation there is an example that shows how to use it from ordinary install, but not from Bower:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>A Simple Page with CKEditor</title>
        <!-- Make sure the path to CKEditor is correct. -->
        <script src="../ckeditor.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <textarea name="editor1" id="editor1" rows="10" cols="80">
                This is my textarea to be replaced with CKEditor.
            </textarea>
            <script>
                // Replace the <textarea id="editor1"> with a CKEditor
                // instance, using default configuration.
                CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
            </script>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Can you help me and show how to use it without this ckeditor.js in my project?

Answer (score 2):

you are going to have a 'bower_components' folder wherever your bower.json file lives. Drill down in it and find the ckeditor.js file you want and then set the path in your html to this path.

it will look something like this:

```
<script src="../bower_components/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

Comment: I'm using jsp, there is way to don't use this <script> section? I think that i saw something more elegant, but it didn't work in my project.

Comment: Im sorry I do not know JSP or the JSP syntax. In order to inject a JavaScript file in html you must use the script tag, unless there is a JSP specific way of doing it which I could not find.